# how to use Jquery functions on Dynaically created elements having IDs

Tags: jquery

I have created some elements dynamically and now i have to add datepicker and use jquery function on them so how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of jquery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function

```
$('.clickme').bind('click', function() {
  // Bound handler called.
});
```

example

```
$('a').live({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseover: function() {
    // do something on mouseover
  }
});
```

Comment: live() method is deprecated since 1.7 (http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use .on() method

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and attach listener to an event from a contaiber.
Example:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.someclass', function() {})
```

This will bind the function() to all 'a' elements witg classe 'someclass' that are children of 'body', using the concept of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).